# XSLT and Muenchian Grouping , Multiple Level Sample

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

I am fairly new to XSLT and never used Muenchian Grouping before. I have been trying to understand the concept by creating a sample for myself, but I can't understand how to obtain the desired output especially when dealing with sub-records.

Let's say we have an input XML that looks like this:

```xml
<OrdersFF xmlns="http://Romp.BizTalk.MapTest">
  <Order>
    <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
    <ItemID>I1</ItemID>
    <TrackingID>T1</TrackingID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
    <ItemID>I2</ItemID>
    <TrackingID>T2</TrackingID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
    <ItemID>I2</ItemID>
    <TrackingID>T3</TrackingID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderID>O2</OrderID>
    <ItemID>I3</ItemID>
    <TrackingID>T4</TrackingID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderID>O2</OrderID>
    <ItemID>I3</ItemID>
    <TrackingID>T5</TrackingID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderID>O3</OrderID>
    <ItemID>I4</ItemID>
    <TrackingID>T6</TrackingID>
  </Order>
</OrdersFF>
```

And we want the output to group by orderid, then item, then trackingcode (we assume each order can have multiple items, and each item can have multiple tracking codes). So the output should look like this:

```xml
<ns0:orders xmlns:ns0="http://Romp.BizTalk.MapTest">
  <order>
    <orderid>O1</orderid>
    <items>
      <item>I1</item>
      <shippingdetails>
        <trackingcode>T1</trackingcode>
      </shippingdetails>
    </items>
    <items>
      <item>I2</item>
      <shippingdetails>
        <trackingcode>T2</trackingcode>
      </shippingdetails>
      <shippingdetails>
        <trackingcode>T3</trackingcode>
      </shippingdetails>
    </items>
  </order>
  <order>
    <orderid>O2</orderid>
    <items>
      <item>I3</item>
      <shippingdetails>
        <trackingcode>T4</trackingcode>
      </shippingdetails>
      <shippingdetails>
        <trackingcode>T5</trackingcode>
      </shippingdetails>
    </items>
  </order>
  <order>
    <orderid>O3</orderid>
    <items>
      <item>I4</item>
      <shippingdetails>
        <trackingcode>T6</trackingcode>
      </shippingdetails>
    </items>
  </order>
</ns0:orders>
```

I tried playing with the XSLT, and this is what I have so far (which is not working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://Romp.BizTalk.MapTest" xmlns:ns0="http://Romp.BizTalk.MapTest">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <!-- Create a key to match against groups in source schema -->
  <xsl:key name="k1" match="Order" use="OrderID"/>

  <xsl:key name="k2" match="Order" use="concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID)"/>

  <xsl:key name="k3" match="Order" use="concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID,'|',TrackingID)"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:OrdersFF" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/s0:OrdersFF">
    <ns0:orders>

      <!-- This will loop through our key ("OrderID") -->
      <xsl:for-each select="Order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k1',OrderID))]">

        <order>
          <orderid>
            <xsl:value-of select="OrderID/text()" />
          </orderid>

          <!-- Another loop... -->
          <xsl:for-each select="Order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k2',concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID)))]">
            <items>
              <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="ItemID" />
              </item>

              <!-- Another loop... -->
              <xsl:for-each select="Order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k3',concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID,'|',TrackingID)))]">
                <shippingdetails>
                  <trackingcode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TrackingID"/>
                  </trackingcode>
                </shippingdetails>
              </xsl:for-each>

            </items>
          </xsl:for-each>



        </order>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </ns0:orders>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could anyone please provide me with any help on how to proceed? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually that far off with your XSLT, it is a very good start, but there are two issues you need to correct. The first one is with namespaces. You are handling namespaces in some places, like so...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:OrdersFF" />
```

But not in all places. The `s0` prefix, in your case, needs to prefix all element names in your XSLT, including when they appear in keys. For example

```
<xsl:key name="k2" match="s0:Order" use="concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID)"/>
```

The second issue is to do with your nest loops. The first nested loop looks like this (after I added the namespace prefixes, that is)

```
<xsl:for-each select="s0:Order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k2',concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID)))]">
```

But you are currently positioned on an `Order` element at this point, so this is looking for child `Order` elements of that, which do not exist! What you need to do here is select all the `Order` elements in the current "group". And to do this, you use the previous key

```
 <xsl:for-each select="key('k1',s0:OrderID)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k2',concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID)))]">
```

Similarly for the `for-each` nested in that.

Try this slightly amended XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://Romp.BizTalk.MapTest" xmlns:ns0="http://Romp.BizTalk.MapTest">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Create a key to match against groups in source schema -->
  <xsl:key name="k1" match="s0:Order" use="s0:OrderID"/>

  <xsl:key name="k2" match="s0:Order" use="concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID)"/>

  <xsl:key name="k3" match="s0:Order" use="concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID,'|',s0:TrackingID)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:OrdersFF" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/s0:OrdersFF">
    <ns0:orders>

      <!-- This will loop through our key ("OrderID") -->
      <xsl:for-each select="s0:Order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k1',s0:OrderID))]">

        <order>
          <orderid>
            <xsl:value-of select="s0:OrderID/text()" />
          </orderid>

          <!-- Another loop... -->
          <xsl:for-each select="key('k1',s0:OrderID)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k2',concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID)))]">
            <items>
              <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="s0:ItemID" />
              </item>

              <!-- Another loop... -->
              <xsl:for-each select="key('k2',concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID))[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k3',concat(s0:OrderID,'|',s0:ItemID,'|',s0:TrackingID)))]">
                <shippingdetails>
                  <trackingcode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:TrackingID"/>
                  </trackingcode>
                </shippingdetails>
              </xsl:for-each>

            </items>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </order>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:orders>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Your answer was extremely useful! :)